# Responsive Design - 320 & up - how to use media queries?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

at the moment I'm trying to get by head around responsive design. One phrase you often hear is 'Mobile first!". I understand what that means, but still I am unsure how to put it into practice.

I am using the 320 and up toolkit/boilerplate which has some media queries already set: `min-width: 480px`, `min-width: 600px`, `min-width: 768px`, `min-width: 992px` & `min-width: 1382px`.
As you probably notice, something like `min-width: 320px` is missing.

Does that mean that I design my page outside the media queries for a width of 320px and then use the media queries to override certain bits that need adjustment?

Comment: It means your first design outside the mediaqueries should focus on the 320 width since it will use whatever is specified. Then you (may) alter it around on those set levels of 480, 600, 768, 992 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write your CSS first without those Media Queries. Actually you should just ignore those Media Queries.

Once you've got your 'mobile' CSS in place (having your browser window real small) you start resizing your browser window. The moment things are starting to look odd, for instance, too much white-space, lines getting to long, you add a new Media Query for that min-width.

Within the new Media Query you adjust for the odd looking things and once you've done that start scaling up again, keep doing this till you reach a point where you think you've got enough screen real estate covered.

There is no one device width as there are thousands of different devices out there so you can't decide on your breakpoints before actually seeing your design in action.